# Error when implementing toast in a fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is the fragment activity:

```
public class in_room_dining extends Fragment {

Button btnord;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_in_room_dining, container, false);
    Button btnord = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ssched);

    btnord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please long press the key",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_in_room_dining, container,false);
}


}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
11-29 15:19:53.913      
894-894/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax, PID: 894
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax.in_room_dining.onCreateView(in_room_dining.java:24)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
```

in_room_dining.java:24 is btnord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

Your `btnord` is probably null, so when you call `SetOnClickListener` on it you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML layout activity_in_room_dining may not contain ssched Button. Check Your layout

Comment: That was the error. However, when I press the button, there is no toast generated.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to not name class variables, the same as method variables, as you have currently.